# How to stream real time data for plotting using OpenGL? If not possible why so?

Tags: c++, opengl, lib

I am working on Technofour and i am using OpenGL to pipe streaming data from device.GNUPlot does have GNUpipe,but how do i stream the data if OpenGL is considered to be used.Any indication of pipe libraries or other programming methods would be much helpful.

P.S:Only in C++